# Percentiles on sequences with duplicate values

Tags: descriptive-statistics, quantiles

Given an ordered sequence of observed values ${1,1,1,2,3}$, both the 20th and the 40th percentile have a value of 1, applying the [Nearest Rank Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#The_Nearest_Rank_method). (Ordinal ranks: $\frac{20}{100} * 5 = 1$, $\frac{40}{100} * 5 = 2$.)

A new observation has the value 1. Which percentile does the new observation fall into? 20th? 40th?

How does one correctly handle percentiles with equal values?

Answer (score 1):

Quantiles are meant for continuous data.  When there are heavy ties, quantiles  have the double problem of being too insensitive to the data and being too sensitive.  As an example of the latter, you can add one data point and shift the estimated quantile greatly depending on where the data times are.  For your situation it is more pertinent to compute the empirical cumulative distribution function, i.e., to invert the quantile function.  The ECDF will have a step at each distinct value occurring in the data, and big steps where there are ties.  This is an accurate reflection of the data.  For summarization you can estimate the ECDF at a few pre-specified $x$-coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

One sensible way of handling this is to say that:

- Before the new observation, percentiles 0 through 60 equal 1, percentiles 60 through 80 equal 2, and percentiles 80 through 100 equal 3.
- After the new observation, percentiles 0 through 66+2/3 equal 1, percentiles 66+2/3 through 83+1/3 equal 2, and percentiles 83+1/3 through 100 equal 3.

So the new value of 1 agrees with the old percentiles 0 through 60, and agrees with the new percentiles 0 through 66+2/3.

If you need values for the percentiles at the points of discontinuity, the [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function#General_distribution_function) approach would clarify “percentiles a through b” in the above as “percentiles which are $>a$ and $\le b$”; for example, the 80th percentile before the new observation would be 2.